# Event fired when any child inside a form changes (is painted)?

Tags: c#, winforms, compact-framework

I'm pretty new to C#, Winforms and the Compact Framework and still didn't wrap my mind around it's event system completely.

I'm looking for a way to add a single event handler to my topmost form, that's called when any of the childs is (re)drawn (or even better, after they're drawn), no matter what type they are. It's also important that I don't need to add any code to the children's themself.

In pseudocode it would could look like this

```
TopMostForm {
    anyChildWasReDrawn() {
      dostuff();
    }
}
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: The past tense "was" is a problem.  Surely there's a better way to achieve what you want, it just isn't clear why you want what you want.

Comment: Most .NET Compact Framework controls do not fire Paint events.  If you *really* need this then you will have to use something like OpenNetCF to tap into the message loop I think.

Answer (score 1):

Look into handling the Paint handler of your children.  For example, in your top most Form you would do something like this:

```
// each child will call the same method when any of them are redrawn
myChild1.Paint += myChildren_Paint;
myChild2.Paint += myChildren_Paint;
mySomeOtherChild.Paint += myChildren_Paint
```

The actual handler itself would look something like this:

```
void myChildren_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    dostuff();
}
```

Note that each child points to this one handler.